# hadoop with MultiInputs, TotalOrderPartitioner-----------with hadoop-eclipse-plugins

Tags: eclipse-plugin, hadoop

I have got two questions:

1. Now I have used hadoop0.20.203 and hadoop1.0.0. But I found that both of the two versions have no classes like MultiInputs ,  TotalOrderPartitioner and so on.   (I open the $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-core-1.0.0.jar file , and don't find the .class files in ort/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/*).
   But I have to use them to do some jobs.  Did I miss anything? What version should I choose?
2. I want to find a plugins for hadoop1.0.2 ( because I found this version the hadoop-core-1.0.2.jar file has the class that I want.)  I want to find one that was compiled. where can I find it?（I have got some but seems unavailable)

In a word, What my object is only to find an available hadoop-*-*-version，and plugins for eclipse. This version can deals with TotalOrder and so on. What should I do?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If they exist in 1.0.2, can you use this version instead? if your cluster currently uses 1.0.0 and you can't upgrade it to run 1.0.2, then you can get the source for these two files and add them into your job jar (as if they were code you had written).

1.0.2 is available for download from the mirrors list:

- http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/

For example: http://apache.mirrorcatalogs.com/hadoop/common/hadoop-1.0.2/hadoop-1.0.2-bin.tar.gz